# How to split columns to multiple rows in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, unpivot

| POLICY_NUMBER | AGENT_NUMBER_1 | AGNT_PCT_RT_1 | AGENT_NUMBER_2 | AGNT_PCT_RT_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SC123456789 | CL00022250 | 50 | CL00050083 | 25 |

We have sample data as shown in the above table, based on which we need to split the data into separate rows accordingly if two or three agents are attached to a policy, then each have their own record and percentage as shown below.

```
SC123456789 ---> CL00022250 ----> 50
SC123456789 ---> CL00050083 ----> 25
```

**SQL Query Used :**

```
SELECT
    TRIM(UPPER(M.SC_CNT_PREF) )|| TRIM(UPPER(M.SC_CNT_NO) )|| TRIM(UPPER(M.SC_CNT_SUF) ) AS POLICY_NUMBER,
        CASE
            WHEN C.SP_AGTNMBR1 != '00000' THEN 'CL000'|| C.SP_AGTNMBR1
        END
    AS AGENT_NUMBER_1,
    TO_NUMBER(C.SP_AGTPCNT1) AS AGNT_PCT_RT_1,
        CASE
            WHEN C.SP_AGTNMBR2 != '00000' THEN 'CL000'|| C.SP_AGTNMBR2
        END
    AS AGENT_NUMBER_2,
    TO_NUMBER(C.SP_AGTPCNT2) AS AGNT_PCT_RT_2,
        CASE
            WHEN C.SP_AGTNMBR3 != '00000' THEN 'CL000'|| C.SP_AGTNMBR3
        END
    AS AGENT_NUMBER_3,
    TO_NUMBER(C.SP_AGTPCNT3) AS AGNT_PCT_RT_3
FROM
    EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_SCIS_MASTER M
    LEFT OUTER JOIN EODS_STG.STG1_EODS_SCIS_SPIA_CONTRACT C ON (
            M.SC_CNT_PREF = C.SP_CNTRPREF
        AND
            M.SC_CNT_NO = C.SP_CNTRNMBR
        AND
            M.SC_CNT_SUF = C.SP_CNTRSUFF
    )
```

Comment: @astentx thanks for your valuable inputs , I have posted the SQL Query used by us , can you Please help me Understand on how we can achieve our results using the Pivot/Unpivot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrap your query inside a sub-query and use `UNPIVOT` with multiple values:

```sql
SELECT policy_number,
       agent_number,
       agnt_pct_rt,
       num
FROM   (
  SELECT TRIM(UPPER(M.SC_CNT_PREF))
         || TRIM(UPPER(M.SC_CNT_NO))
         || TRIM(UPPER(M.SC_CNT_SUF)) AS POLICY_NUMBER,
         CASE WHEN C.SP_AGTNMBR1 != '00000' THEN 'CL000'|| C.SP_AGTNMBR1 END
           AS AGENT_NUMBER_1,
         TO_NUMBER(C.SP_AGTPCNT1) AS AGNT_PCT_RT_1,
         CASE WHEN C.SP_AGTNMBR2 != '00000' THEN 'CL000'|| C.SP_AGTNMBR2 END
           AS AGENT_NUMBER_2,
         TO_NUMBER(C.SP_AGTPCNT2) AS AGNT_PCT_RT_2,
         CASE WHEN C.SP_AGTNMBR3 != '00000' THEN 'CL000'|| C.SP_AGTNMBR3 END
           AS AGENT_NUMBER_3,
         TO_NUMBER(C.SP_AGTPCNT3) AS AGNT_PCT_RT_3
  FROM   /*EODS_STG.*/STG1_EODS_SCIS_MASTER M
         LEFT OUTER JOIN /*EODS_STG.*/STG1_EODS_SCIS_SPIA_CONTRACT C
         ON (
               M.SC_CNT_PREF = C.SP_CNTRPREF
           AND M.SC_CNT_NO = C.SP_CNTRNMBR
           AND M.SC_CNT_SUF = C.SP_CNTRSUFF
         )
)
UNPIVOT (
  (agent_number, agnt_pct_rt) FOR num IN (
    (agent_number_1, agnt_pct_rt_1) AS 1,
    (agent_number_2, agnt_pct_rt_2) AS 2,
    (agent_number_3, agnt_pct_rt_3) AS 3
  )
)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/lfQSMxCk)

Answer (score 0):

With data and explanation you posted, `union` might be a simple solution to this problem.

Sample data:

```
SQL> WITH
  2     test (policy_number,
  3           agent_number_1,
  4           agnt_pct_rt_1,
  5           agent_number_2,
  6           agnt_pct_rt_2)
  7     AS
  8        (SELECT 'SC123456789', 'CL00022250', 50, 'CL00050083', 25 FROM DUAL)
```

Query:

```
  9  SELECT policy_number, agent_number_1 AS agent_number, agnt_pct_rt_1 AS agnt_pct_rt
 10    FROM test
 11  UNION ALL
 12  SELECT policy_number, agent_number_2, agnt_pct_rt_2 FROM test;

POLICY_NUMB AGENT_NUMB AGNT_PCT_RT
----------- ---------- -----------
SC123456789 CL00022250          50
SC123456789 CL00050083          25

SQL>
```